# What would be the math symbol for representing a fraction?

Tags: html

I would like to shown `2/3` (i.e. 2 divided by 3) in a HTML format and I don't want to use `/`. What would be the right symbol to format fractions/division using HTML?

Comment: When I use mixed fractions on both sides of an arithmetic operator it doesn't seem to render well. I would prefer to see denominator below the numerator, so that it can be easily understood by the end user.

Comment: I am not sure about ":", since it will be used for ratios.

Comment: <pedant>What *is* and what *would be* are two different things</pedant>

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Judging by your comments, it looks like you're specifically asking how to display fractions.  If that's the case, many fractions are defined as HTML entities.  As an example, a few of those entities are:

```
&frac12; &frac14; &frac18; &frac23; &frac25; &frac34; &frac38;
```

**Result:**

> ½ ¼ ⅛ ⅔ ⅖ ¾ ⅜

Note that not all browsers support those named entities, but you could use their Unicode values instead.  If you want to be able to display any fraction and not just the ones that have entities, you can use the fraction slash entity, `&frasl;` ( ⁄ ).  This character overlaps pixels from the preceding and following characters to make a very neat fraction.  It's best used when combined with superscript and subscript numbers:

```
<sup>39</sup>&frasl;<sub>40</sub>
```

**Result:**

> <sup>39</sup>⁄<sub>40</sub>

**Further reading:**
 http://changelog.ca/log/2008/07/01/writing_fractions_in_html

If the font you're using supports it, you may also be able to paste the subscript and superscript numbers directly into your HTML from an application like charmap.exe.  See [Konrad Rudolph's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449191/what-would-be-the-math-symbol-for-representing-a-fraction/4452068#4452068) for an example.

Comment: That is cool. These are some more words to pad out my comment so I can post.

Comment: In Firefox 3.6.13 `18`, `23`, `25` and `38` don't work. In Chrome 8.0.552.224 they all work.

Comment: @webbiedave: thanks, I hadn't checked 3.6 but they were working in Firefox 4b7.  I've updated the answer to point out that not all browsers support those named entities.

Comment: Excellent! There are a few more Unicode fractions build-in to some fonts: http://amp-what.com/#q=fraction

Answer (score 48):

To generate the division sign `÷`, type `&divide;` or `&#247;`

Answer (score 16):

Use the entity `&#247;`

÷

[HTML ASCII Characters](http://www.nationalfinder.com/html/char-asc.htm)

Comment: If you use the code tags around it (as in `\``), you can embed that rather than writing it out in words. `&#247;` (I made the edit)

Comment: Thanks Jeff (although a sick part of my head actually enjoyed writing it out in words :-)

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at this article: [Writing Fractions in HTML](http://changelog.ca/log/2008/07/01/writing_fractions_in_html)

Since you want to see denominator below the numerator you can use the code:

```
<sup>2</sup>
&frasl;
<sub>3</sub>
```

Which will look like:

<sup>2</sup>
⁄
<sub>3</sub>

Answer (score 11):

By the way, you don’t necessarily resort to HTML tags and HTML entities (arguably, the `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags aren’t well-suited for the task). You can also rely solely on Unicode:

Predefined vulgar fractions:

- U+00BC ¼
- U+00BD ½
- U+00BE ¾
- U+2153 ⅓
- …

And then there’s the fraction slash (U+2044, ⁄) and the superscript and subscript numbers at positions U+00B9, U+00B2, U+00B3 and starting at U+2070. Using these, you can get arbitrary vulgar fractions:

⁴⁵⁄₂₃

This was all written as seen on the screen ([look at the source](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65ca183f-0602-48d6-8d23-fb8a0a0f1046/view-source) if you don’t believe me!), no HTML code whatsoever. However, not many fonts support all of the number forms so the HTML variant may be more usable in practice.

Answer (score 9):

Since you prefer to display in numerator/denominator format, use  `&frasl;` in conjunction with HTML `sup` and `sub`

Example:

```
<sup>4</sup> &frasl; <sub>9</sub>  will give you
```

<sup>4</sup> ⁄ <sub>9</sub>

To be more safe, you can use the decimal variant: `&#8260;`

Example:

```
<sup>4</sup> &#8260; <sub>9</sub>  will give you
```

<sup>4</sup> ⁄ <sub>9</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You could use MathML to write more complex maths formulas and equations.

http://www.mozilla.org/projects/mathml/demo/basics.xhtml