# How to display horizontal fraction symbol

Tags: html, css

I want to imitate fraction numbers like this: http://projectpophealth.org/images/Multi-Provider_Measure_Page.png

I've already seen alternative ways to display fractions: [What would be the math symbol for representing a fraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449191/what-would-be-the-math-symbol-for-representing-a-fraction)

But I really like the look and feel of the horizontal symbol. How do I display it in HTML?

Comment: Thats relatively easy and you should be able to do it

Comment: I've thought about it and it seems a bit more difficult for me. I believe I need three separate components: the numerator, the denominator, and the horizontal bar. I imagine that I need to use divs and place them in blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented that its difficult for you to do so, here's the answer. I've used inline elements and I am turning them to a block level so that they render one below another, and for separating them out, I use `border-bottom` on the first `span` element.

Rest, for the top offset, I use `position: relative;` to settle it down... Rest is self explanatory.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HFk5g/)

**HTML**

```
<div>(<span><span>18</span><span>26</span></span>)</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #515151;
}

div > span {
    font-size: 18px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div > span > span {
    display: block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
}

div > span > span:first-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #515151;
    color: green;
}

div > span > span:last-child {
    color: tomato;
}
```

I feel that these types of expressions or over complex ones will get cumbersome to do with CSS Only, hence, take a look at [Mathjax](http://www.mathjax.org/)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get started, thank you. I tried it myself and really thought my way was way too amatuer-ish: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Btw, let's say with your code, the denominator is in the hundredths. How would you center justify the numerator? In my jsfiddle I was also trying to address that issue with text-align.

Comment: Put `text-align: center;` in `div > span > span`

Comment: :facepalm: myself. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

I've made up a simple plain html/css solution, you may want to adjust the font to one more suitable by the way.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78jA5/1/)

```
<body>
    <div class="fraction">
        <p class="num">6</p>
        <p class="dem">14</p>
    </div>
</body>

.fraction{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 1em;
}

.fraction > .num {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #808080;
    padding:4px;
    margin:0 0 4px 0;
}

.fraction > .dem{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.fraction > .num:before{
    content: "(";
    font-size:2em;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0.2em;
}

.fraction > .dem:after{
    content: ")";
    font-size:2em;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0.2em;
}
```

Comment: As I continued to implement these fraction CSS's, I found that your solution is responsive, meaning no matter on what size screen, your solution maintains the visual integrity of the fractions. Good job man! I am currently using your implementation.